# How to use a timestamp from wide format dataframe to separate long format dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to use a timestamp from one data frame (in a wide format) in order to determine if the values in my long format data frame came before or after the timestamp.

In other words, I have two data frames:  df1 = patient demographics, df2 = patient hospital labs.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID': ['MR1','MR2','MR3'], 'Start_time':[11, 12, 1]}
data2= {'ID': ['MR1','MR1','MR1','MR2','MR2','MR2'],'Order_time':[11,1,4,10,12,2],'lab_value':[10,14,12,10,8,16]}

#I am just using int instead of timedata for simplicity in this example

df1=pd.DataFrame(data)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
df1
df2
```

The IDs in dataframe 1 are unique, but repeated as any given ID can have multiple labs.  I want to use the start_time to determine if order_time is before or after start time (for each MR). This will allow me to split the dataframe into pre-labs and post-labs. Eventually I will pivot the data and merge into a single dataframe in the wide format.

Is there a simple way to use the time stamp from the first dataframe for each MRN to split the data in the second dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question right. If your problem is with relating these two dataframes in terms of timestamp, you can simply join dataframes and then filter as you wish.

After your codes,

```
df_merge = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID'], how='outer')
df_merge['PRE_LAB'] = (df_merge['Order_time'] < df_merge['Start_time']) * 1
# Decide what happens when both timestamps, 
#`Start_time` and `Order_time` are equal if it is possible in your case.

print(df_merge)

    ID  Start_time  Order_time  lab_value  PRE_LAB
0  MR1          11        11.0       10.0        0
1  MR1          11         1.0       14.0        1
2  MR1          11         4.0       12.0        1
3  MR2          12        10.0       10.0        1
4  MR2          12        12.0        8.0        0
5  MR2          12         2.0       16.0        1
6  MR3           1         NaN        NaN        0

# Filtering on PRE_LAB
df_pre_lab = df_merge[df_merge['PRE_LAB'] == 1]
df_post_lab = df_merge[df_merge['PRE_LAB'] == 0]

print(df_pre_lab)
    ID  Start_time  Order_time  lab_value  PRE_LAB
1  MR1          11         1.0       14.0        1
2  MR1          11         4.0       12.0        1
3  MR2          12        10.0       10.0        1
5  MR2          12         2.0       16.0        1

print(df_post_lab)
    ID  Start_time  Order_time  lab_value  PRE_LAB
0  MR1          11        11.0       10.0        0
4  MR2          12        12.0        8.0        0
6  MR3           1         NaN        NaN        0
```